# Using rostest with gtest value-parameterized tests

Tags: ros, rostest, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a test suite that implements Google's value-parameterized tests using a `TEST_P` test type and `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` to define a series of tests.

When I run `rostest` on my `.test` file, only the tests defined with `TEST_F` are run, not the parameterized ones. However, when I run `rostest --text` with the same `.test` file, all tests, including those defined with `TEST_P`, are run.

<strike>What is causing the difference, and how can I cause the standard `rostest` call to run all of my tests and record the results to the standard XML file?</strike>

EDIT: It turns out that in fact all of the tests are being run and recorded in the XML files. However, the results are not aggregated and output to the console unless `--text` is specified. This is very bad, because even deliberately failing tests (with `ASSERT_TRUE(false)`) does not cause `make test` or `rostest` to report failure. As a result, any number of tests would fail, and I would never know unless I manually checked the XML, which is counter to the entire point of gtest.

Is this expected behavior? Or a bug I should file?

EDIT 2: Apparently, I need more karma to attach a file, so I have uploaded a complete [test package](http://jerrytowler.com/temp/rostest_sample.tar.gz) to my website instead (it's a complete package, in case I mangled some configuration to cause this error). Note that `make test` returns success, as does `rostest launch/sample.test`, while the XML file gets written correctly. Running the executable itself, with `./sampletest`, also correctly reports the failure. Additionally, I found that, if there are only `TEST_P` cases in the test file, they get output to the console as expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10835/using-rostest-with-gtest-value-parameterized-tests/) by [jatowler](https://answers.ros.org/users/934/jatowler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-08-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-09**:
I ran the rostest sample and I get test failures.  Output here: http://pastebin.com/vyPZpzHi

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2012-10-21**:
I ran into a similar issue with the standard node-level-integration tests.

**Comment by [tulku](https://answers.ros.org/users/2276/tulku/) on 2014-04-11**:
I'm seeing this same problems. I have an integration test, which have some regular TEST() tests and also some parametrized tests (declaring the class and then using TEST_P). The parametrized tests get ignored when running rostest. I don't see them in the rosunit xml either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostest parses the recorded results in the XML file to determine whether or not the test fails.  The aggregation and output of the summary is also produced from these XML results.  The fact that the test results are not being picked up implies that the results in the XML file are not parsed correctly, or the XML file is being output in an unexpected location.  In either case, it would be useful to have a small sample case to try and reproduce with.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-02**:
marking as closed per comment on test failure above